# memory issues with pickling 25 files 80-84 MB each

Tags: python, memory-management, twitter, pickle

i am processing millions of tweets. each file i am pickling is created after about 400k processed tweets. each process tweet contains a dictionary and another 4 fields of int. after dumping all the files im loading them back and merging each few documents based on their contents.

after i finished processing them i am trying to load them one file at a time so i can do further analyzing and sort them based on alphabetical first letter but the problem is that even after i load 1 file my RAM becomes almost full (90-95 percent) and the program just stops and it takes like 40 minutes to continue working i am assuming due to memory issues.

when i try to lower the amount of tweets  i dump in each file to 250k tweets and not  400k then each file size obviously decreased   but the Ram use goes up from 50 percent to 70-90 percent and i dont understand why. can someone explain why this is happening how to fix it? should i save fewer files that weight more or save more objects that weight less? this is the code. is there a way to read faster and serialize a dictionary?

```
def index_documents(counter,config):
    file_list=[]
    indexer = Indexer(config)
    file_num=0
    for i in range(0, counter ):
        file_list.append("D:\Downloads\Data\Data\parsed_doc\\chunk" + str(i) +".pkl")
    start_time=time.time()
    for file in file_list:
        pickle_in = open(file, "rb")
        dict_i = pickle.load(pickle_in)
        pickle_in.close()
        os.remove(file)
        for key in dict_i.keys():
            indexer.add_new_doc(dict_i[key])
        indexer.dump_all(file_num)
        file_num+=1
```

the dump all functions is where i take each pickle file and make few other pickle files from him.

thank you

Comment: Pickling is an operation with pretty rare use cases. Why do you pickle the files?

Comment: im pickling the files because im saving each tweet in a dictionary and after like million tweets it becomes to big for me to have it in memory so im writing it to disk and since its a dictionary i need to serialize it. and since its a big object (sizewise) im using pickle since i read json is slower

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need just text files for processing. If you need a standard format that compatible with Python dict, then you are looking for JSON.

To [dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) json:

```
with open(os.path.join("path", "to", f"{file_name}.json"), "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(data, write_file)
```

To [load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) json:

```
with open(os.path.join("path", "to", f"{file_name}.json"), "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
```

#### Pickling vs JSON serialization

> “Pickling” is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is converted into a byte stream, and “unpickling” is the inverse operation, whereby a byte stream (from a binary file or bytes-like object) is converted back into an object hierarchy.

> JSON is built on two structures:
> A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
> An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

And what is the most significant, JSON serialization is converting an object to a string.

Comment: isnt JSON slower then pickle?

Comment: Of course not, JSON is plain text but pickling is binary code serializing.